The GET method is not supported for route : Supported methods: POST (php artisan:serve working fine but in aws ebs with nginx getting this error)
When i run my application with php artisan:serve its working fine, but in production server (aws elastic beanstalk with nginx server) my app is throwing this error.
my view is as following:
<form action="{{ route('sign-up.company.store') }}" method="POST">@csrf
my route definiton:
Route::post('company/signup/store',[RegistrationController::class, 'signUpCompanyStore'])->name('sign-up.company.store');
and my controller method has something like following actions:
//To be noted for security reasons i've removed some code from my controller method
public function signUpCompanyStore(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'first_name'           => ['required','max:60'],
            'last_name'            => ['required','max:60'],
            'email'                => ['required','email','unique:users,email']]);
        $role = CompanyRole::where('name', 'Company')->first();
        // new user registation
        $company_name = $request->first_name.$number;
        $noWhiteSpaceString = str_replace(' ', '',$company_name);
        $smailletter = Str::lower($noWhiteSpaceString);
        $address = UserAddress::where('user_id',1)->first();

        $data = User::create([
            'role_id'         => 0,
            'password'        => Hash::make($request->password),
            'email_verified_at'=> $address->is_verified == 2 ? now() : null,
            'status'=>1
        ]);
        Mail::to($data->email)->send( new SendEmailVerification($data));
        $package = Package::where('slug','free')->first();
        $order = CompanyOrder::create([
            'order_id'     => id_generate(1,8),
            'status'       => 1,
        ]);

        Invoice::create([
            'user_id'      => $order->user_id,
            'status'       => $order->status,
        ]);

        if ($address->is_verified == 1) {
            if ($address->cron_job_mail == 1) {
                dispatch(new SendEmailVerificationJob($data))->delay(now()->addSeconds(5));
            } else {
                $email = new SendEmailVerification($data);
                Mail::to($data->email)->send($email);
            }
        }
        Auth::login($data,true);
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('success','Registration Successfuly !');
  }




Bring up your browser's developer console, and watch the Network tab when you submit the form. Do you see any sort of redirect, such as HTTP -> HTTPS?

Yes @aynber i see following:
Request URL: http://example.com/company/signup/store Request Method: POST Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently Remote Address: IP_ADDRESS:80 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
and then getting status code 405 afterwards

@aynber i have the default elastic beanstalk nginx config except some configs for php loaded in the .platform here is the php.conf
in which i beleive the " location / "  block is handling all requests and passing them to PHP-FPM for processing right?

The 301 redirect is changing your POST to a GET, which then throws the error because it no longer matches the intended method. It doesn't say what it's being moved to. If it's HTTP -> HTTPS, then use HTTPS all the way through. If it's another URL, then you'll need to fix that.

@aynber yes i finally figured it out, my laravel application was making http request to the server so i had to set my app environment to production in my .env and here are following changes i did to my /app/Providers/AppserviceProvider.php afterwards;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
Then, within the boot method, i added the following code:
public function boot(): void     {         if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {             URL::forceScheme('https');         }     }
Thank you.
